# A solution space for a consistent homogeneous system which has 5 equations and 4 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

A solution space for a consistent homogeneous system (which has 5 equations and 4 variables) is not a subspace from R5:

A) True

B) False

Answer given is true but I think it should be false.
I took an analogous condition, instead of R5 i took R3 and then took three equation:

1)x=y

2)2x=2y

3)3x=3y

All these three equation are homogeneous consistent equations.

Since x=y forms plane that pass through origin and so it's a subspace of R3, and therefore I think that if there are 4 variable and 5 equation then that should form subspace of R5. Please correct me, if I am wrong.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution space is a subspace of the *domain* (the space that you are taking the variables from). What is the domain here? It is $\mathbb{R}^4$.

In general, a system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables can be represented by $Ax = b$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, which we can think of as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $b$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. So the solution space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. (In this case, $m = 5, n = 4$.)

Now, your intuition is not really wrong, in the sense that you could think of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$, so that it is also a “subspace” of $\mathbb{R}^5$. But usually when we say that a set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we mean firstly that it is a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I think this is what the question was trying to get at.

Comment: So, technically is it right to say that it is a subspace of R5?

Comment: No. A subspace first of all has to be a subset of the underlying vector space.

Comment: okay got it, thank you